# Django user table dropped and cannot re-migrate

Tags: django, postgresql

For reasons best not explained, I deleted all tables and migration files in the database for my personal Django project. I thought running `makemigrations` and `migrate` would set it back up, however the migrate command fails.

Running `python manage.py migrate` results in:

> django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not
>   exist.

I can run the server. However when going to the admin page (http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/), I get the exception:

> During handling of the above exception ('SessionStore' object has no
>   attribute '_session_cache'), another exception occurred:
>
> The above exception (relation "django_session" does not exist LINE 1:
>   ...ession_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_se... ^ )
>   was the direct cause of the following exception:

The request information shows "[unable to retrieve the current user]".

I was able to re-create superuser, and I have all the tables except for the models in my main app:

```
UNKNOWN_USER_ID = 11    

def get_unknown_user():
        return User.objects.get(id=UNKNOWN_USER_ID).pk

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, verbose_name='Created')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=get_unknown_user,
                                   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created', verbose_name='Created By')
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Modified')
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=get_unknown_user,
                                    related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_modified', verbose_name='Modified By')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class CollectionItem(CommonInfo):
    NONE_SELECTED = 0
    DONATED = 1
    PURCHASED = 2
    TRADED = 3
    FOUND = 4
    CREATED = 5

    METHOD_ACQUIRED_CHOICES = (
        (NONE_SELECTED, ''),
        (DONATED, 'Donated'),
        (PURCHASED, 'Purchased'),
        (TRADED, 'Traded'),
        (FOUND, 'Found'),
        (CREATED, 'Created')
    )

    date_acquired = models.DateField(default=date.today, verbose_name='Date Acquired')
    method_acquired = models.IntegerField(choices=METHOD_ACQUIRED_CHOICES, default=NONE_SELECTED,
                                          verbose_name='Method Acquired')
    available_for_trade = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Available For Trade')
    tags = TaggableManager(verbose_name='Tags')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, verbose_name='Description')
    collection = models.ForeignKey('Collection', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Collection ID')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class CollectionType(CommonInfo):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Collection(CommonInfo):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    collection_type = models.ForeignKey('CollectionType', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=get_unknown_user,
                              related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_owned')
    # fieldset = models.ForeignKey('CollectionFieldset', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class CollectionItemImage(CommonInfo):
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Image')
    collection_item = models.ForeignKey('BottleCap', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Collection Item')
    order_in_collection = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Order', default=1)


class BottleCap(CollectionItem):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name='Company')
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name='Brand')
    product = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name='Product')
    variety = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name='Variety')
    color = models.IntegerField(default=None, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Color')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, verbose_name='Text')
    underside = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, verbose_name='Underside')
```

Comment: Show the full output of the migration command.

Comment: Try running the migrations in a different order, by specifying the app name in the migrate command

Comment: @KlausD., I added in the full output.

Comment: Please readd the output and format it as code. As a quote it is unreadable.

Comment: Formatting as code isn't any more legible. Is there a certain part you would like me to extract?

Comment: You need to share your model structures

Comment: @ruddra, I added in my models (for the app that isn't getting migrated)

Comment: What is thr code for `get_unknown_user`

Comment: @ruddra, Added the function get_unknown_user to the top of the models code.

Comment: I think you are on the right track. This part looks like it could present issues when the user table has no user with pk 11, which is the case now.

Comment: @ruddra, That solved the issue. I fixed the model so the user foreign key fields changed the on_delete constraints from PROTECT to CASCADE. This allowed me to remove references to the get_unknown_user, allowing me to get to the admin page. And best of all, this made me rethink that cascade in this case is probably better than protect.

Answer (score 2):

For dropping your whole data, or just from an app, in psql it is necessary to do this in the chronological order:

First delete your migration-fies in your appfolder (app/migrations).

Then:

Drop DB in psql:

```
  # DROP DATABASE dbname;
```

Create DB in psql:

```
  # CREATE DATABASE dbname;
```

Make migrations again:

```
  manage.py make migrations (appname)
```

Then migrate:

```
 manage.py migrate (appname)
```

Comment: I was able to do all of your steps, however I get back to the same error when running migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to start all over again and you are not bothered about the previous data .Create a superuser after deleting the db.sqlite3 and all the migrations other than **init**.py . Don't delete **init**.py .

1. Delete migrations and db.sqlite3
2. run makemigrations
3. run migrate
4. create superuser

Comment: No, I don't care about previous data. I had already deleted the tables. I also am running postgres, not sqlite3.

Comment: Delete the migrations and run make migrations and then migrate .